# Where can I get data on supernovae captured both by the Hubble and an earth telescope?

Tags: supernova

I want to compare data on supernovae that are both captured by the Hubble telescope and at least by one earthly telescope. The problem - where can I get this data?

Comment: This might be tricky; some pointers... Assuming you are interested in recent supernovae, the vast majority of these are now announced via the [Transient Name Service (TNS)](https://www.wis-tns.org). You could use their [search page](https://www.wis-tns.org/search) to find possible or confirmed SNe. I suspect you *won't* want to select any of the HST instruments as the `Discovery Instrument` as most SNe will be found by ground-based surveys. Searching for >6 months ago will give you SNe which would be outside the HST proprietary period  when doing a search on the same coords in the MAST archive